# Put python in R while creating R package

Tags: python, r, package

I am creating an R package but need to use function written in Python, I wonder is there any way to call Python script internally assuming that user only need to install one-in-all R package? I am planning to submit the package to Bioconductor or CRAN

Your help is really appreciated!

Comment: is there a reason you can translate the python to R?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. because the whole thing (and also dependencies) was written/combined by different languages.

Comment: Can’t you make the `reticulate` library a dependency of your package?

Comment: If you are using `system` or `system2` to call `python` (not recommended for anything beyond trivial use), then your only requirement as far as R package installation is concerned is what your functions do if the user does not have python installed/available in the underlying system (e.g., *command not found*). If you are using `reticulate`, you cannot have an all-in-one R package without encompassing all of `reticulate`'s functions into yours (which is just copying, technically legal but perhaps not worth it). ... and it is still assuming that `python` is available.

Comment: I don't think you mean this, but just in case ... if you are asking if it is feasible/reasonable to include a complete (albeit perhaps mini) distribution of the python interpreter and required packages within an R package ... **feasible?** perhaps, I really would not want to try ... **reasonable?** not just no, but heck no, from several angles.